# Running a function in a Parent component that also calls a function in Child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have two components which are in different files, Home and Game. Home is the parent component of Game. I am trying to make it so that when I hit a button in the Home component, it runs the startNewGameHome() function in the Home component **AND** the startNewGame() function in the Game component. The reason why these functions are in separate components is because they rely on the states in their respective components.

This is my Home component (import Game statement not shown):

```
export default function Home() {
    const [isGamePlaying, setIsGamePlaying] = useState(false);
    const [whichRound, setWhichRound] = useState(1);
    const [numberRounds, setNumberRounds] = useState(10)
    const [isGameOver, setIsGameOver] = useState(false);
    const [totalAttempts, setTotalAttempts] = useState(1);
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

    const gameref = useRef();
//...

    const GameOverPage = () => {
        // other page content
                        </Box>
                        <Button
                            bg="black"
                            color="white"
                            size="lg"
                            onClick={() => {
                                startNewGameHome(); // This is the start button that runs the //startNewGameHome function
                            }}
                        >
                            Play Again
                        </Button>
                    </VStack>
                </Box>
            </Flex>
        );
    };
    

    // This is the startNewGameHome() function

    function startNewGameHome(){
        setIsGameOver(false);
        setTotalAttempts(0);
        setScore(0);
    }

    return (
        <Flex h="100%" height="100vh" direction="column" ml="4vw" mr="4vw" pt="24px" align='center'>
            <Navbar/>
            <Flex display="flex" w="100%" h="100%">
                {!isGamePlaying && <StartPage />}
                {isGamePlaying && !isGameOver && <Game reference={gameref}
                    whichRound={whichRound}
                    updateRound={handleRoundUpdate}
                    numberRounds={numberRounds}
                    totalAttempts={totalAttempts}
                    setTotalAttemps={setTotalAttempts}
                    startNewGameCallback={startNewGameHome}
                />}
                {isGamePlaying && isGameOver && <GameOverPage/>} // Play again button implemented here as part of the GameOverPage
            </Flex>
        </Flex>
    )
}
```

Here I store the Game component as a ref, which is returned by the Home component. I also pass the startNewGameHome function into the startNewGame field of the Game component. What I want to happen is when the startNewGameHome function is run when the Play Again button is hit, it also runs the corresponding startNewGame function in the Game component, as seen below. I also want it so that when the Game component mounts, the startNewGame function AND the startNewGameHome function are both run.

Game.js (Game component):

```
const Game = ({whichRound, numberRounds, updateRound, totalAttempts, setTotalAttemps, startNewGameCallback}) => {
    const [scrambled, setScrambled] = useState("");
    const [unscrambled, setUnscrambled] = useState("");
    const previousUnscrambledRef = useRef('');
    const [userGuess, setUserGuess] = useState(""); 
    const [score, setScore] = useState("");
    const [displayFeedback, setDisplayFeedback] = useState(false);
    const [feedback, setFeedback] = useState("");
    const [attemptsLeft, setAttemptsLeft] = useState(3);
    const [readyNewRound, setReadyNewRound] = useState(false);
    const [isLoadingWord, setisLoadingWord] = useState(false);
    
    // Start Game - runs everytime a new game is started/page is refreshed
    useEffect(() => {
        startNewGame(); // Call the function via the prop
     }, [startNewGameCallback]);     

    function startNewGame({startNewGameCallback}){
        setScrambled(""); // Clear the scrambled word
        setUnscrambled(""); // Clear the unscrambled word
        previousUnscrambledRef.current = '';
        setUserGuess(""); // Clear the user's guess
        setDisplayFeedback(false); // Hide any feedback
        setFeedback(""); // Clear the feedback
        setAttemptsLeft(3); // Reset attempts left
        setReadyNewRound(false); // Not ready for a new round
        setisLoadingWord(false); // Stop loading word
        updateRound(0);
    }

    function newRound(){
        fetchWord();
        updateRound(1);
        setAttemptsLeft(3);
        setDisplayFeedback(false);
        setReadyNewRound(false);
    }

// Other content

}

export default Game
```

Currently, this produces the following error:
Cannot destructure property 'startNewGameCallback' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'startNewGameCallback' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.

I know that I'm probably not following good practice with React since I'm new to it. So if there is a better and working way to do this, please let me know!